# MongoDB Aggregation - How can i apply query expression into match stage using spring-data-mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have documents with dynamic fields and I would need to find a count of matching records for a given complex query criteria

**Example Entity**

```
@Document(collection = "UserAttributes")
public class UserAttributesEntity {

    @Id
    @Getter
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    @Getter @Setter
    private String userId;

    @NotNull
    @Getter @Setter
    private Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
}
```

**Example Data**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6164542362affb14f3f2fef6"),
    "userId" : "89ee6942-289a-48c9-b0bb-210ea7c06a88",
    "attributes" : {
        "age" : 61,
        "name" : "Name1"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6164548045cc4456792d5325"),
    "userId" : "538abb29-c09d-422e-97c1-df702dfb5930",
    "attributes" : {
        "age" : 40,
        "name" : "Name2",
        "location" : "IN"
    }
}
```

**Expected Query Expression**

```
"((attributes.name == 'Name1' && attributes.age > 40) OR (attributes.location  == 'IN'))
```

The MongoDB Aggregation Query is as below for $match, however same is not available through spring mongo db api:

```
{ 
    $expr: 
    { 
        "$and": [{
            "$gt": ["$attributes.age", 40]
        }, {
            "$eq": ["$attributes.name", "Name2"]
        }] 
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything here?

Library using: org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project stage allow us to use query expression and I converted my approach to the below to achieve the results:

```
private Mono<Long> aggregate() {
    final Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation
            .newAggregation(
                    Aggregation.project("userAttributes.playerLevel", "userAttributes.name")
                        .andExpression("((userAttributes.name == 'Name1' && userAttributes.age > 40) OR (userAttributes.location  == 'IN'))")
                        .as("result"),
                    Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("result").is(true)),
                    Aggregation.group().count().as("count"));

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(UserAttributesEntity.class), Map.class)
       .map(result -> Long.valueOf(result.get("count").toString()))
       .next()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Support for `$expr` operator in spring-data-mongodb library is still non-existent. However there is a work around solution using MongoTemplate to solve this problem -

Aggregation.match() provides an overloaded method that accepts `AggregationExpression` as a parameter. This method can be used to create the query for `$match` aggregation pipeline with `$expr` operator like this -

**Example usage of AggregationExpression for $match operator -**

```
Aggregation aggregationQuery = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(AggregationExpression.from(MongoExpression.create("'$expr': { '$gte': [ '$foo', '$bar'] }"))));
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregationQuery, Entity.class);
```

**Above code is the equivalent of query -**

```
db.collection.aggregate([{"$match": {"$expr": {"$gte: ["$foo", "$bar"]}}}])
```

Code for the question would be something like this -

```
Aggregation aggregationQuery = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(AggregationExpression.from(MongoExpression.create("'$expr': { '$and': [{ '$gt': ['$attributes.age', 40] }, { '$eq': ['$attributes.name', "Name2"] }] }"))));
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregationQuery, Entity.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own `AggregationOperation` to deal with your varying conditions. **Haven't tried my own code**, but it should be something like that:

```
AggregationOperation myMatch (List<Document> conditions) {

    return new AggregationOperation() {

        @Override
        public String getOperator() {
            return "$match";
        }

        @Override
        public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
            return new Document("$match",
                    new Document("$expr",
                            new Document("$and", conditions)
                    )
            );
        }
    };
}
```

and call it that way (to match your question query):

```
void callMyMatch() {
    myMatch(List.of(
        new Document("$gt", List.of("$attributes.age", 40)),
        new Document("$eq", List.of("$attributes.name", "Name2"))
    ));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @orid. Yes, I could do the above approach or even I could try creating Criteria object dynamically based on the query too, but I will be expecting some complex queries with nested conditions, and so hoping if I can simply use SPEL to evaluate the query expression? 

similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69635474/mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-count-no-of-records-that-are-matching-a-complex-c

Looking for a way to directly pass in the expression without building it like above: ```"((attributes.name == 'Name1' && attributes.age > 40) OR (attributes.location  == 'IN'))"```